# java this keyword inside constructor

Tags: java

i am currently taking java class, and today my teacher said something that my mind didn't accepted i could be wrong. following code ,

```
       class Ab{
         int x;
         int b;

           public Ab(int x, int b){
               this.x = x;
               this.b = b;
           }


           public static void main(String[] args){
               Ab x = new Ab(4,5); // this is where my teacher confused me 

           }
}
```

my teacher said `x Ab = new AB(4,5);` will get x object invoking constructor passed in constructor to refer to it with `this keyword`, what about anonymous classes like `new Ab(2,4);` now what will `this keyword` refers to? in my point of view `this` inside constructor has no link with reference variable until constructor create the object and return the reference to variable.

Comment: `this` refers to the current object.

Comment: Your class defines field `int x`, but in the constructor you're using `this.a`. Either you meant `int a` and `this.a`, or `int x` and `this.x`. Which one is right?

Comment: Why is your code formatted like that?

Comment: oh my mistake , its this.a

Comment: @markspace i am new to stackoverflow sorry for that .

Comment: Just to clarify... Is your teacher saying that by writing `Ab x = new Ab(4,5);`, `x` value will be `4`?? Because that is wrong. But your question is not clear, sorry, please explain it better.

Comment: @walen does 'this keyword' inside constructor has relation to reference variable x before constructor finish creating object and return the reference to x variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about anonymous classes like `new Ab(2,4)`;

This is not an anonymous class. It's an expression that creates a new object of type AB. The value of that expression is a reference to the object. The value of `this` within the AB constructor is a reference to the object. And the value of `x` below is a reference to the object. They're all references to the same object.

```
Ab x = new Ab(4,5); // this is where my teacher confused me
```

> in my point of view this inside constructor has no link with reference variable until constructor create the object and return the reference to variable.

The `this` inside the constructor has no need to refer to another reference variable. It points to the same object as `x` will when the constructor returns.

A reference is not the object itself. You can think it of one of possibly multiple pointers to an object.

Comment: now that clarifies it for me thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to type `this` because in constructor's scope name of our variables `a` and `b` are hidden behind the names of parameters `a` and `b`. `this` means just the current object of the class.

**EDIT:**
Object is created with `new` keyword. The `x` variable is just a reference to the object. In the class methods we can refer to the current object with `this` and somewhere else we have to make a reference. So when your teacher told about `this` refering to `x` he meant refering to the object which is accessible with `x`.

Comment: if u can read the last paragraph i explained every thing .

Comment: does 'this keyword' inside constructor has relation to reference variable x before constructor finish creating object and return the reference to x variable?

Comment: @RidaBatool I have edited my answer to explain everything to you, accept it as the correct answer if it helped!

Comment: thank u so much . i got the correct answer above